# How do I make a PersistentVolumeClaim to regain access to dynamically provisioned released PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created/provisioned a PVC and PV dynamically from a custom storage class that has a retain reclaimPolicy using the below k8s resource files.

```
# StorageClass yaml spec
# kubectl apply -f storage-class.yaml

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: fast-ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
  fstype: ext4
  replication-type: none
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

```
# PersistentVolumeClaim yaml specs
# kubectl apply -f mysql-pvc.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-mysql
  name: test-mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: "fast-ssd"
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 51G
```

Below are the sequence of steps to followed to reproduce my scenario:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntu/test$ kubectl apply -f mysql-pvc.yaml 
persistentvolumeclaim/test-mysql-pv-claim created

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntu/test$ kubectl get pvc,pv
NAME                                        STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/test-mysql-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-a6bd789c-9e3c-43c8-8604-2e91b2fee616   48Gi       RWO            fast-ssd       7s

NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-a6bd789c-9e3c-43c8-8604-2e91b2fee616   48Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/test-mysql-pv-claim   fast-ssd                6s

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntu/test$ kubectl delete -f mysql-pvc.yaml 
persistentvolumeclaim "test-mysql-pv-claim" deleted

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntu/test$ kubectl get pvc,pv
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-a6bd789c-9e3c-43c8-8604-2e91b2fee616   48Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   default/test-mysql-pv-claim   fast-ssd                44s

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntutest$ kubectl apply -f mysql-pvc.yaml 
persistentvolumeclaim/test-mysql-pv-claim created

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:/home/ubuntu/test$ kubectl get pvc,pv

NAME                                        STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/test-mysql-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-fbc266ab-60b0-441b-a789-84f950071390   48Gi       RWO            fast-ssd       6m6s

NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-a6bd789c-9e3c-43c8-8604-2e91b2fee616   48Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   default/test-mysql-pv-claim   fast-ssd                7m6s
persistentvolume/pvc-fbc266ab-60b0-441b-a789-84f950071390   48Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound      default/test-mysql-pv-claim   fast-ssd                6m5s
```

As we can see from the last part of the output new PVC is bounded to new PV, not to the old released PV.

So can we make some changes in mysql-pvc.yaml file so that our PVC can again be reassigned/bounded to old release PV, as that PV will have important data that we need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your reclaim policy is "retain", any change in the pvc YAML will not work.

As per Kubernetes doc:

> The Retain reclaim policy allows for manual reclamation of the resource. When the `PersistentVolumeClaim` is deleted, the `PersistentVolume` still exists and the volume is considered "released". But it is not yet available for another claim because the previous claimant's data remains on the volume. An administrator can manually reclaim the volume with the following steps.

- Delete the `PersistentVolume`. The associated storage asset in external infrastructure (such as an AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or Cinder volume) still exists after the PV is deleted.
- Manually clean up the data on the associated storage asset accordingly.
- Manually delete the associated storage asset, or if you want to reuse the same storage asset, create a new `PersistentVolume` with the storage asset definition.

Ref:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain